# Hibernate не хочет преобразовывать результат

Tags: java, hibernate

Делаю выборку через createSQLQuery, возвращаться должна таблица ProductBrand.

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
                    "SELECT pb.* " +
                    "FROM " +...

result = (List<ProductBrand>)query
                    //.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(ProductBrand.class))
                    .list();
```

Так ответ получается всё равно Object
setResultTransformer начинает ругаться на отсутствие сеттера(!), но он есть!

```
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for concrete_volume on class tables.cas.ProductBrand
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я не прав?
**UPD 1**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wk_cas_product_brand")
public class ProductBrand extends ModelTables {
...
    /**V м3 бетона на изделие*/
    @Column(name = "concrete_volume", nullable = false)
    private Double concreteVolume;
...
    public Double getConcreteVolume() {
        return concreteVolume;
    }

    public void setConcreteVolume(Double concreteVolume) {
        this.concreteVolume = concreteVolume;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: можете прикрепить класс с объявлением поля `concrete_volume`?

Comment: @Komdosh прикрепил.

Comment: а `from` у вас от класса ProductBand?  Или просто из таблицы по типу `product_band as pb`?

Comment: Да, wk_cas_product_brand as pb(

Comment: в таком случае, он не понимает, что `public void setConcreteVolume(Double concreteVolume)` относится к `concrete_volume` нужно писать `SELECT pb.concrete_volume as concreteVolume FROM ...`, но вообще нужно добавлять Entity к запросу через `query.addEntity(ProductBrand.class)`. Вы обращали внимание на репозитории `spring data`?

Comment: можно и создать сеттер с именем setConcrete_volume

Comment: @Komdosh Спасибо. Пришлось делать маппинг самостоятельно.

Comment: Не страдайте, воспользуйтесь jparepository

Comment: @Komdosh Я не использую spring...

Comment: Кстати по моему можно повесить аннотацию @Column на сеттер